# Pseudo-selectores CSS no funcionan

Tags: css, css3

Estoy tratando de hacer dos lineas con unas características, con la clase linea. Cuando intento aplicar un estilo diferente a la segunda linea, utilizando los pseudo-selectores no funciona.

```
.linea{
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: orange;
    left: 00px;
    display: block;
}
```

La idea es cambiar el color y el margen. He probado con los selectores: **.linea:last-child** y **.linea:nth-child(2)** y no funciona con ninguna de las dos.

Decir que se trata de un div, y que no están dentro de ningun otro contenedor, directamente en el body del documento.

Answer (score 2):

Según la especificación de nivel 3 de css, para que la pseudoclase `:last-child` funcione, debe haber un elemento contenedor del selector al cual se aplica.

En teoría el mismo principio aplica para `:nth-child`

```css
.linea {
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: orange;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}

.linea:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}

.linea:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="linea">Línea 1</div>
  <div class="linea">Línea 2</div>
  <div class="linea">Línea 3</div>
  <div class="linea">Línea 4</div>
  <div class="linea">Línea 5</div>
</div>
```

Si hay otros elementos distintos a los cubiertos por el selector, aparentemente "deja" de funcionar la pseudoclase, pero no es así, simplemente se está utilizando de forma incorrecta según la especificación de CSS, pues `last-child` fue creado para seleccionar el último elemento de un determinado nivel, no para aplicarse al último elemento de una clase específica como lo pretendes hacer:

```css
.linea {
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: orange;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}

.linea:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}

.linea:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="linea">Línea 1</div>
  <div>Texto</div>
  <div class="linea">Línea 2</div>
  <div class="linea">Línea 3</div>
  <div>Texto</div>
  <div class="linea">Línea 4</div>
  <div>Texto</div>
  <div class="linea">Línea 5</div>
  <div>Más texto</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pero el contenedor sería el body del documento, no? O debe estar incluido en un contenedor div?

Comment: El elemento `<body>` podría ser el contenedor, eso es correcto, siempre y cuando no haya ningún otro elemento al mismo nivel de los elementos del selector.

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código HTML para poder responder adecuadamente la pregunta.